# Dynamic File Paths

Tags: c#, file, dynamic, path

Suppose I had a particular directory on C# in the following format:

@"C:\blabla\bla\0.0.1.63\blabla.png";

The "0.0.1.63" changes occasionally due to updates to the software and so on.

I want to know how I can assign a "..\" - similar effect for that particular directory to be dynamic. Because I do not know the update sequence.

So, how do I make it so that the directory stays the same, while that particular part of the directory (0.0.1.63) is an "unknown" directory.

Comment: Please clarify: 1) Where is "0.0.1.63" in the path? (I don't see it) 2) the fact that you have a mix of "\" and "/" is part of the problem? 3) What does it mean to *assign* "..\"? By the way, I suspect all you need is [`System.IO.Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: "Dynamic" is a buzzword as used here. Do you mean your actual problem is you want to find a directory with an unknown name (in this case `0.0.1.63`) in a directory with a known name (in this case `C:\blabla/bla/`)? See [`DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58(v=vs.110).aspx) and see if you can find any that matches your preferences.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the path when you get it?

Comment: @MarkHall It's a project I'm working on. Rather not specify since that's private and irrelevant.

Comment: I was wondering on usage to better construct an answer..

Comment: @MarkHall My apologies, I assumed you thought I was fooling around with illegal intentions.

Comment: @MarkHall I am planning on replacing a particular file within that directory with another file that is uploaded (in directory) to the program via a simple openfiledialog method

Comment: Ok, so you want set the target directory in the openfiledialog, are there going to be multiple directorys, ie. 0.0.1.63 ,  0.0.1.64 etc? or just one sub directory?

Comment: @MarkHall Just one, but that one folder changed in name everytime there is an update in the software. edit: However the files within that foler always remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratedirectories%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefilesysteminfos%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to find your file, you could then strip the filename from the FileInfo objects FullName and use the result. Something like this should work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = getPath();
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}

private string getPath()
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\blabla\bla\");
    foreach (var d in di.EnumerateDirectories())
    {
        foreach(var fi in d.EnumerateFileSystemInfos())
        {
            if (fi.Name == "blabla.png")
            {
                return fi.FullName.Replace(fi.Name,"");
            }
        }
    }
    return di.FullName ;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad I was able to be of help.